# WPF Runtime xaml/form designer

Tags: .net, wpf, designer

I'm wondering if it is possible to launch the visual studio wpf design surface at runtime in a similar way you could the WinForms surface? Also willing to consider paid for 3rd party controls or open source projects. Ideally I want to let users design their own windows

Comment: Hi, you may use blend or the vs editor and use designmode data. If you are using a ViewModelLocator, like the one that comes from Galasoft MVVM Light(avaliable through nuget), you can do it quite handy here. Or simply use d:DataContext with some fake model feeding you designtime data.

Comment: I don't want to just load Xaml, I want the user to essentially be able to create it, either via the VS designer or some 3rd party component. Something not a million miles from this is not too bad http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/569753/WPF-Form-Designer-Prototype-MVVM

Comment: I see. I've actually developed what you are describing there, well a converter actually. Wouldn't go down that rode again! :) Sorry I don't know. From experience I've learned to stick with vs & blend, to much hassle with people using the tool and not understanding neither xaml, bindings, commands etc etc. But your case ofc is different than mine was(rather big customizable LOB applications).

Answer (score 4):

Maybe https://github.com/icsharpcode/WpfDesigner is the right component for you?

Comment: Maybe the user isn't active any more (I answered 2 years later!)